# iTextSharp.5.5.13 C#, I have to add elements until I run out of space, if I run out I add the total and continue on another page

Tags: c#, itext

I have a PDF that adds a header above and below the PC via event while in the middle I have a table in which I have to insert elements that have various attributes so the columns have dynamic size, each page can have N elements but it must necessarily have the total below the elements referring to the page.
So I have to dynamically calculate the height of the table (adding the size with a space of the footer and header which is static anyway).

The problem is that iTextSharp doesn't tell you the size if you don't instantiate the document so I created a fake Table and every time if the total is less I added the row, when I get to exceed the limit I don't add that element but I add the total and change the page .

The problem is that by doing 1/10 of the tests it doesn't work and it moves the content to another page that only has 2-4-6 elements and I can't make it work

this is the method to see table size:

```
        public static float CalculatePdfPTableHeight(PdfPTable table)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A3.Rotate()))
                {
                    using (PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                    {
                        doc.Open();
                        doc.Add(table);
                        doc.Close();
                        return table.TotalHeight;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Inventory:

```
private PdfPTable Inventory(PdfPTable tb)
        {
            PdfPCell cl;
            var itemsInPage = Model.ListaMateriali.Skip(ItemCounterList).ToList();

            PdfPTable fake = new PdfPTable(tb);
            var elementTake = 0;

            foreach (var item in itemsInPage)
            {
                // take the element of line
                foreach(var t in Header)
                    created a cell.....

                    fake.AddCell(cl);
                }
                if ((DocumentType.Height - 340) < CalculatePdfPTableHeight(fake))
                    break;

                tb = new PdfPTable(fake);
                elementTake++;
            }
            ItemCounterList += elementTake;

            //add row total
            tb.AddCell(cl);

            return tb;
        }
```

The Body:

```
        private void Body(Document doc)
        {
            Model.List = Model.List.OrderBy(it => it.Number).AsParallel().AsOrdered().ToList();
            while (ItemCounterList < Model.List.Count)
            {
                var headerInvetory = HeaderInventory();
                var inventory = Inventory(headerInvetory);
                doc.Add(inventory);
                doc.NewPage();
            }
            doc.Add(TotalPriceInventory());
            doc.NewPage();
            doc.Add(ListSummay());
        }
```